# labels size in amCharts (it hides them too early)

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I have a simple bar chart with amCharts 4 and my problem is, that the chart starts hiding labels too early. (there's still enough space to display them)

Does someone have an idea, how to fix that, in the official documentation I couldn't find anything useful.

[image: example of chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 1;
```

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so simple, thank you very much!